# How can I add two columns to a data.table with random sampling of a binary possibility?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table of children where I know one ear was affected but I do not know which one. I want to randomly allocate the issue to either the right ear or the left ear. I do not care which but if the one ear is designated "in" then the other ear must be designated "out".

That is easy I thought for just one child

```
sample(c("in", "out"), size = 2)
```

Then I thought that I could simply assign the results to the right and left column.

```
children <- data.table(child = c("Gertrude", "Penelope", "Joshua", "Sebastian", "Jane", "Ravi"))
children[, c("right", "left") := sample(c("in", "out"), size = 2)]
```

I have messed around a lot with the code and I keep getting the following message. It is not helping me.

> Error in `[.data.table`(children, , `:=`(c("right", "left"),
> sample(c("in",  :    Supplied 2 items to be assigned to 6 items of
> column 'right'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to
> make this intent clear to readers of your code.

I also tried adding `by=child`.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first assign `right` (or `left`) and then assign the opposite one to other side.

```
library(data.table)

children <- data.table(child = c("Gertrude", "Penelope", "Joshua", 
                                  "Sebastian", "Jane", "Ravi"))

children[, right := sample(c('in', 'out'), .N, replace = TRUE)]
children[, left := fifelse(right == 'in', 'out', 'in')]
children

#       child right left
#1:  Gertrude    in  out
#2:  Penelope    in  out
#3:    Joshua   out   in
#4: Sebastian   out   in
#5:      Jane   out   in
#6:      Ravi    in  out
```

---

To add two columns in one go we need output to be a list.

```
children[, c("right", "left") := as.list(sample(c("in", "out"))), children]
```

Comment: OK. I could use your workaround. Yes, Thank you. However, my roadblock demonstrates that there is something fundamental about data.table that I do not understand. I am looking to increase my abilities with data.table. Where was I going wrong?

Comment: 1) `c("right", "left") := ` suggests you want to add two columns but you do not provide values for them. 2) `sample(c("in", "out"), size = 2)` will just give two values however you want values which is equal to number of rows (`.N`) in your data.

Comment: But can't I process per row?

Comment: @Farrel I see what you were trying to do with `sample(c("in", "out"), size = 2)`. We can do that but the output should be a list. See updated answer.

Comment: Yip that is it. Remember I said, "_I have messed around a lot with the code_". I knew about the fact that I needed to generate list of two items so I tried `...c("right", "left") := list(sample(c("in", "out")), by = child...`. I did not realize I had to use `as.list` and not `list`.